# Both arduino ide and idf esclipe have the same syntax and example.?

Tags: c, arduino, embedded

I was looking for a tutorial for ESP32. I discovered a few tutorials, each of which uses a different IDE, such as the Arduino IDE or IDF . So they're both using c. But do these two ides have the same syntax? Is it possible to use the same code on an Arduino Ide? If I take a tutorial for IDF Ide, whatever I learn can I apply to an Arduino Ide?

Comment: Arduino isn't using C, but C++.

Comment: IDF is a software development kit (SDK), not an IDE.  Moreover an IDE does not define the language, it merely provides an integrated editing, build, load and debug environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax doesn't depend on the IDE, there's standard C, and there's extensions, which depend on the compiler being used. An IDE may support more than one compiler. In general it doesn't matter at all unless you're using extensions, which should be restricted to platform-specific abstractions and other low-level stuff, not to be seen in application code.

Answer (score 0):

The development environment does not define the language.  However Arduino Sketches are compiled as C++, and the libraries are C++.  While Sketch encourages an *object-based* rather than *object-oriented* programming approach, you can use OOP if you choose, or you can write C-like code, but some C++ specific language features are unavoidable to use the library.  And it is still compiled as C++, so it *is* C++ regardless of the paradigm.

IDF is an SDK not an IDE. The library is a C interface, with C-linkage, but is entirely interoperable with C++, but it is entirely different to the Arduino Wiring API. Since the hardware access, and the hardware itself differ considerably, you will not be able to reuse code across the two environments where that code accesses the platform specific libraries.

If you want a more Arduino-like experience on ESP32, then you would do better perhaps to use the specific [Arduino-ESP32](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/installing-the-esp32-board-in-arduino-ide-windows-instructions/) add-in for Arduino itself.  However the IDF is more capable and fully featured, including an RTOS - it is more suited to large and complex applications.  However, not being an IDE, you have to work a little too pull together a complete development environment. Options suggested [in the IDF documentation](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/getting-started-micropython-esp32-esp8266/) are Eclipse or VSCode - neither are as simple as Arduino IDE or Web Editor.

There are other options for ESP32 development including:

- [Micropython](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/getting-started-micropython-esp32-esp8266/)
- [Espruino (JavaScript)](https://www.espruino.com/ESP32)
- [NodeMCU (Lua](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/dev-esp32/))

Comment: I wouldn't recommend VSCode to beginners and I wouldn't recommend Eclipse even to my worst enemies. If one isn't satisfied with the default IDE, then maybe consider Microsoft Studio (free, based on VS) or a commercial IDE.

Comment: @Lundin Indeed, my first draft I had that I'd struggle to recommend either (to anybody), but felt that was an opinion that had no real place in the answer.  ESP32 IDF itself is not really for "beginners" in any event, and if you begin with Arduino, you are likely to remain a beginner.  I was largely trying to correct the misunderstanding evident in the question that there was some sort of equivalence between Arduino and IDF.  They are not comparable in the way the OP seems to think.

Comment: (That comment was supposed to say Microchip* Studio of course. Heh, "freudian slip" as it's essentially VS. The IDE formerly known as Atmel Studio.)